# Implement Continuous Conversations

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I would like to implement the continuous conversation flow as depicted below. Could you please guide me how this could be made possible using Bot Framework and LUIS ?

**User:** Can you convert $100 to Euro

**Bot:** $100 are €89.2

**User:** and to pounds ?

**Bot:** $100 are £78.542

**User:** and to rupees ?

**Bot:** $100 are ₹6530.97

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Money prebuilt entity to help recognize the intent to convert, as well as the entities of dollars, euros and pounds.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/pre-builtentities

Add the money prebuilt entity to your LUIS model.  Then, add an intent called ConvertMoney and add utterances like: Convert $100 to Euro, Convert $100 to pounds, etc.

Once your LUIS model is trained and published, create a bot that uses a LuisDialog to recognize the intents and entities.  Lastly, you will need to use a 3rd party service to do the actual conversion.

Comment: Thanks Eric, But I would specifically like to understand about how can I build a flow wherein user could keep asking the questions (like to punds, to rupees etc.) and FormBuilder could respond them. To give more clarity look at the below example


**User:** What is the weather today at Mumbai

**Bot:** Thunderstorm with heavy wind

**User:** and Tomorrow

**Bot:** Showers with light wind

Comment: You can use the State Client to track where they are in the conversation.  Organize your dialogs in such a way that you check the conversation state and show a different result based on what the user had previously been shown.  For instance: "What is the weather today at Mumbai" at this point you add to conversation state that the user is retrieving weather for Mumbai, and return them the result.  When the next message comes in, you check the conversation state for previous intent of weather with city.

Comment: Conversation flow is one of the most difficult things to get right in Dialog management.  Here is some reading that might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow

Comment: Thanks Eric for your guidance, I will work towards this and let you know.